# Will not boot after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 - wlan device note found

Tags: 18.04, wireless, upgrade

HP EliteBook 8460P

Blank screen, switched to terminal to see what was going on. Please see attached images. Any ideas?? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance! --Tim[image: boot screen cap]

Comment: I disabled all of the mount points in fstab with no change. Any idea on how to disable / delay wlan0? Live cd boots ok and am able to get WiFi working there. Thanks, Tim

Comment: delet /etc/rc.local

Comment: Unfortunately, I ended up starting a fresh install instead of an upgrade to 18.04 so I don't know if the answer about deleting /etc/rc.local would have worked.